# inserting data into database using two table

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

in my views.py

```
def addinfo(request):
    profile_form = ProfileForm()
    book_form = BookForm(instance=Profile())

    if request.POST:

        profile_form=ProfileForm(request.POST)

        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile=Profile_form.save()

            book_form=BookForm(request.POST,instance=profile)

            if book_form.is_valid():
                book_form.save()
```

models.py is

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age=models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
    db_table=u'Profile'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%d %s %s %s %d" % (self.pk, self.first_name, self.last_name, self.email,self.age)



class Book(models.Model):
    book_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    profile=models.ForeignKey(Author)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'Book'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%d %s %s' % (self.pk, self.book_name, self.publisher_name)
```

This is to save the data into two different models,i am using forms in this.One model gets updated,the another table data is not getting inserted.Without saving the page gets refreshing.What would be the problem.

Comment: you cannot instantiate a BookForm with a Profile instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def addinfo(request):
    profile_form = ProfileForm()
    book_form = BookForm(instance=Profile())

    if request.POST:
        profile_form=ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile=Profile_form.save()

            book = Book(profile_id=profile.id)
            book_form=BookForm(request.POST,instance=book)
            if book_form.is_valid():
                book_form.save()
```

Comment: I'm confused you define `profile=models.ForeignKey(Author)` but in your `addinfo view` you make a `Profile instance for Book` which is not relative. Or typo error?

Comment: it cannot be a typo, since `Book` instance requires a `Profile` Foreign key to be defined... it should be `book_form = BookForm(instance=Book(profile_id=???))` so my suggestion is to set `profile` attr (in `Book` model) as not mandatory.

Comment: What I mean is he set the ForeignKey to `Author` which is not in the model. Maybe it is `profile=models.ForeignKey(Profile)`, he forgot to change it.

Comment: oh, you're right! I wrote about another aspect, the code has many unclear aspects/typos both in model definition and in class instantiation

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood what you are trying to do, you should replace

```
book_form=BookForm(request.POST,instance=profile)
```

with

```
book = Book(profile_id=profile.id)  
# EDIT shameless copy and paste from Catherine's answer to avoid "profile_id not defined" error
book_form=BookForm(request.POST,instance=book)
if book_form.is_valid():
    book_form.save()
```

---

**EDIT**:
As an alternative you may alter your `Book` model in order to make instance optional:

```
profile=models.ForeignKey(Author, null=True)
```

in this way, your view will become:

```
def addinfo(request):
    profile_form = ProfileForm()
    book_form = BookForm()

    if request.POST:
        profile_form=ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile=Profile_form.save()
            book_form=BookForm(request.POST)
            if book_form.is_valid():
               book = book_form.save(commit=False)
               book.profile = profile
               book.save()
```

see the notes in [this paragraph](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form) for an explanation of `commit=False` part

Comment: hi after doig that i am getting error as profile_id could not be null

Comment: I've edited my answer but since it is almost the same answer of Catherine, please upvote her if you like :)